# How to have two different heroku apps on one repo

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

So before I had a `heroku` and a github remote `origin` linked to my local files. My client now has a production heroku account, but I still want to keep the free hobby server for staging.

OLD:

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/fun-app-1.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/fun-app-1.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/gh/funapp.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/gh/funapp.git (push)
```

NEW:

```
heroku-production   https://git.heroku.com/fun-app-2.git (fetch)
heroku-production   https://git.heroku.com/fun-app-2.git (push)
heroku-staging  https://git.heroku.com/fun-app-1.git (fetch)
heroku-staging  https://git.heroku.com/fun-app-1.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/gh/funapp.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/gh/funapp.git (push)
```

So now I have `origin`, `heroku-staging`,`heroku-production`. This works fine for pushing `git push heroku-staging master` but now I cant run `heroku logs`, `heroku run ...`

How can I make this work? Ideally with `heroku-production run XXX` or `heroku-staging logs` or similar.

Comment: You need to use herokus dashboard

Answer (score 2):

The Heroku toolbelt supports referencing multiple applications with the `--app` option:

```
heroku logs --app fun-app-1
heroku restart --app fun-app-2
```

My company has dozens of applications, and we got tired of typing that all the time, so if you like, we wrote [a little wrapper gem](https://github.com/apartmentlist/h) to define shortcuts.